# Any way to make an anchor tag clickable if it's placed inside router-link?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have this component:

```
<template>
  <div id="news" class="news page">
    <router-link class="news-card" :to="{ name: 'news-article'}">
      <a :href="'https://www.facebook.com'">www.facebook.com</a>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

and I want to make the `anchor` tag clickable so that it opens the URL `https://www.facebook.com`.

I've tried lifting it in priority with `z-index` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.news {
  .news-card {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    a {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      &:hover {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

The hover effect on the `anchor` works, but not the `href` property. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't nest `<a>`, it's not valid.

Comment: the router-link is already a component that returns an anchor tag. no need for an extra anchor tag inside

Comment: Why you putting that `<a>` inside the router link? Router link is a link to different part of your app. Putting anchor into it does not make sense at all

Comment: You might investigate why your link wasn't clickable to begin with. That's a head-scratcher.

Answer (score 1):

`router-link` is basically a `a` tag, so you basically have an `a` tag inside of an `a` tag. I assume when clicking on [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) it would take you to  `{ name: 'news-article' }` instead of facebook.

This is what you wanna do I guess..

```
<template>
  <div id="news" class="news page">
    <router-link class="news-card" to="https://www.facebook.com">
         www.facebook.com
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```